# Issue around keeping image of deceased father in clinic

Tags: halal-haram, image, photos

My father was a Unani Doctor. He passed away in July 2019. We are 2 brother and I am younger. My elder brother is 20 years older than me and practiced for some time with my father. Our clinic was on the ground floor of the house we lived. It's well known by my father's name/fame in the nearby cities. Patients recognised him.

After his death, he took over the entire clinic and left me and my mother. Fortunately, half of the house where we lived was under my mother's name. As I was also in the same profession and completed my studies around the time of his death only, me and my mother started a new clinic in half of the house.

Now there are 2 clinic's and both claim to be old place of my late father. Recently, my elder brother started keeping my father's image framed and hanged at several places within the clinic. This is affecting our business as patient's still come due to my father's name only and recognise the photo.

Several people have advised to hang a photo in our clinic as well but we don't know if its right. Before my brother had started keeping my father's image, both of the clinic's were getting almost 50-50% of patients.

Main Query: Is it ok for me to keep image of my deceased father hanged inside the clinic under the given circumstances as it has high impact on patients coming to my clinic?

Comment: I am sorry about your father's death. Congratulations on starting a new clinic. I would like to express my opinion, but unfortunately, it is a personal opinion and we are not allowed to do so here.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

*On Hanging up a photo of your father:*

Most Scholars recommend not to do so; most opt for makruh, some for haram.

*On the fame of your father:*

Islam does not support heritage of merit. Neither your brother nor you can inherit the merits (neither the sins) of your father. You are both liable for what you do yourselves. Your merit in profession is to help your patients the best according to your knowledge.

*On competition with your brother:*

It would of course be favourable if you could find a good agreement with your brother but you are not obliged to do so. Your brother is obliged to respect his (and your) mother but she cannot force him to have a good relation to you. If you want to solve the problem of competition with your brother, ask God to help you.